# Find Location of Index Match

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to find an answer to what I assume is a simple question. I need to find what cell an index match is referring to.

Example: I have an example below of what it looks like. The "Index Matched" column is returning the number of black "as color tee" of size L that is currently there. I need this to be updated with the QTY, which is easy enough to do. But I need to find where the 8 is coming from. I know its cell F3 on the sheet, but how to I extract that information.

[image: index match example]

The formula I have there is:
`=INDEX($C$3:$N$57,MATCH(X8&Y8,$A$3:$A$57&$B$3:$B$57,0),MATCH(Z8,$C$2:$N$2,0))` It searches a table fine. When it finds it, can I get what cell that data is from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved my issue.

It was simple as I thought.

The solution is to add `Cell("Address",` to the front of the formula.
So that `=INDEX($C$3:$N$57,MATCH(X8&Y8,$A$3:$A$57&$B$3:$B$57,0),MATCH(Z8,$C$2:$N$2,0))` would, instead of producing the result of say "8" it would produce "$F$3" with the line:

`=CELL("Address", INDEX($C$3:$N$57,MATCH(X8&Y8,$A$3:$A$57&$B$3:$B$57,0),MATCH(Z8,$C$2:$N$2,0)))`

Answer (score 0):

I modify your formula as

```
="(" & MATCH(X8&Y8,$A$3:$A$57&$B$3:$B$57,0) & "," & MATCH(Z8,$C$2:$N$2,0) & ")"
```

see if works. It is in (row, column) form. If you want other form, there is way to further transform it.

Comment: While that does get the location, I need the Cell Location. This gives 1,4. I need the cell like "F8". I'm running a VBA script that changes the data in the cell it finds, which is the reason